# R: Different Ways of Selecting Variables using the "which()" Statement

Tags: r, select, rows, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

Suppose I have the following data set:

```
num_var_1 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 1)
num_var_2 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
num_var_3 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_4 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
num_var_5 <- rnorm(1000, 10, 10)

factor_1 <- c("A","B", "C")
factor_2 <- c("AA","BB", "CC")
factor_3 <- c("AAA","BBB", "CCC", "DDD")
factor_4 <- c("AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE")
factor_5 <- c("AAAAA","BBBBB", "CCCCC", "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFFF")

factor_var_1 <- as.factor(sample(factor_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)))
factor_var_2 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_2, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2)))
factor_var_3 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_3, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)))
factor_var_4 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))
factor_var_5 <-  as.factor(sample(factor_4, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)))

my_data = data.frame(num_var_1, num_var_2, num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_1, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5)


> head(my_data)
  id num_var_1 num_var_2 num_var_3 num_var_4  num_var_5 factor_var_1 factor_var_2 factor_var_3 factor_var_4 factor_var_5
1  1  9.439524  5.021006  4.883963  8.496925  11.965498            B           AA          AAA         CCCC         AAAA
2  2  9.769823  4.800225 12.369379  6.722429  16.501132            B           AA          AAA         AAAA         AAAA
3  3 11.558708  9.910099  4.584108 -4.481653  16.710042            C           AA          BBB         AAAA         CCCC
4  4 10.070508  9.339124 22.192276  3.027154  -2.841578            B           CC          DDD         BBBB         AAAA
5  5 10.129288 -2.746714 11.741359 35.984902 -10.261096            B           AA          AAA         DDDD         DDDD
6  6 11.715065 15.202867  3.847317  9.625850  32.053261            B           AA          CCC         BBBB         EEEE
```

If I want to select rows from this data based on some condition, I can use the "which()" statement. For example:

```
#select rows based on some condition

my_rows = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 > 3 & my_data$num_var_2 > 7 & my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c("A", "B")), ]

#count number of rows 

 dim(my_rows)

[1] 569  10
```

**My Question** Is it possible to re-write the above "which()" statement such that other variables  from the data frame appear in the "which()" statement, but are "ignored"? (i.e. 569 rows are still produced)

For example (pseudocode):

```
my_rows = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 > 3 & my_data$num_var_2 > 7 & my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c("A", "B") & my_data$num_var_3 = "does not matter"& my_data$num_var_4 = "does not matter" & my_data$num_var_5 = "does not matter" & my_data$factor_var_2 = "does not matter" & my_data$factor_var_3 = "does not matter" & my_data$factor_var_4 = "does not matter"& my_data$factor_var_5 = "does not matter"), ]
```

Even though `num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5` are not being used to select rows, can they still be written in the "which()" statement (such that 569 rows are still produced)?

```
#pseudo code

    my_rows = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 > 3 & my_data$num_var_2 > 7 & my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c("A", "B") , my_data$num_var_3 = "all values" & my_data$num_var_4 = "all values" & my_data$num_var_5 = "all values" & my_data$factor_var_2 = "all values" & my_data$factor_var_3 = "all values" & my_data$factor_var_4 = "all values" & my_data$factor_var_5 = "all values"), ]
```

I thought of a lengthy way to do this:

```
        my_rows_1 = my_data[which(my_data$num_var_1 > 3 & my_data$num_var_2 > 7 & my_data$factor_var_1 %in% c("A", "B") & my_data$num_var_3 >= min(my_data$num_var_3) & my_data$num_var_4 >= min(my_data$num_var_4) & my_data$num_var_5 >= min(my_data$num_var_5) & my_data$factor_var_2 %in% levels(my_data$factor_var_2) & my_data$factor_var_3 %in% levels(my_data$factor_var_3) & my_data$factor_var_4 %in% levels(my_data$factor_var_4) & my_data$factor_var_5 %in% levels(my_data$factor_var_5)), ]

 dim(my_rows_1)
[1] 569  10
```

But is there a "wildcard" symbol which can be used to completely ignore variables `num_var_3, num_var_4, num_var_5, factor_var_2, factor_var_3, factor_var_4, factor_var_5` ? I know that the easiest thing to do is (obviously) not write them in the "which()" statement - but can the "which()" statement be written in such a way that all variables are included, but the ones that are not desired can be assigned a single value to indicate "ignore"?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you want an intermediate state of which returned in addition to it's TRUE result, as FALSE is essentially = ignore. So perhaps ask twice in opposite directions and combine?

Comment: How about `which(var1 > 0 & !logical(length(var2)))`? Here, `var2` is "included" but its value does not affect the result of `which`.

Comment: whay would you ever want to include variables inside a logical function but ignore them? I am struggling to understand why the need for this bizarre thing. This looks like a xy problem to me.